# mb_strtoupper() No funciona En servidor

Tags: php, servidor

tengo un código que me genera unos informes en excel, utilizo  mb_strtoupper() para colocar en mayúsculas los resultados , en localhost me funciona con todas las letras, pero en el servidor solo coloca las normales, es decir las ñ, y tildes no les aplica para colocarlas en mayúsculas, tengo que activar algo en el servidor?, es la versión de php? hay algo que lo solucione? gracias.

EJEMPLO
palabra muñoz:

Servidor local

```
 mb_strtoupper($resulSet['primer_apellido']);
Resultado: MUÑOZ
```

Servidor de hosting

```
 mb_strtoupper($resulSet['primer_apellido']);
Resultado: MUñOZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [**`mb_strtoupper`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtoupper.php) admite un segundo parámetro en el cual se le puede especificar la codificación. Si este segundo parámetro es omitido será usado el valor de codificación que tenga por defecto el servidor.

Si le indicas UTF-8 debería funcionar:

```
$string=$resulSet['primer_apellido'];
echo mb_strtoupper($string, 'UTF-8');
```

**Codificación en el servidor**

Para establecer/obtener la codificación de caracteres interna del servidor en PHP existe la función **[`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)**

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* Establecer la codificación de caracteres interna a UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

/* Mostrar la codificación de caracteres interna en uso */
echo mb_internal_encoding();
?>
```

**Otra alternativa: CSS**

Se puede hacer también por CSS, usando **[`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)**:

```
$string=$resulSet['primer_apellido'];
echo '<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">'. $string. '</span>';
```

***Algunos ejemplos con CSS:***

```css
.mayusculas 
{
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>Ejemplo, aplicando directamente el estilo (no recomendado):</p>
<p>muñoz - > <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">muñoz</span> esto no lo quiero en mayúsculas</p>
<p>áéíóú - > <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">áéíóú</span> esto tampoco...</p>
<hr />
<p>Ejemplo usando <strong>buenas prácticas (con nombres de clases)</strong>:</p>
<p>muñoz - > <span class="mayusculas">muñoz</span> esto no lo quiero en mayúsculas</p>
<p>áéíóú - > <span class="mayusculas">áéíóú</span> esto tampoco...</p>
```

Comment: Wow!, me salvaste el día, Muchísimas gracias.